# Calling method with an implicit parameter

Tags: scala, function, implicit

I have the following method:

```
def test[T](implicit ev: T <:< Int, t : T) = println(t)
```

How can I call it? I tried

```
test(10)
```

But the compiler prints out the following error:

```
Error:(19, 9) not enough arguments for method test: (implicit ev: <:<[T,Int], implicit t: T)Unit.
Unspecified value parameter t.
    test(10)
        ^
```

First of all, I thought that we could just omit implicit parameters and specify only explicit ones. And secondly, why does it's saying that that the parameter `t` is implicit?

```
implicit t: T
```

How does it actually work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> First of all, I thought that we could just omit implicit parameters and specify only explicit ones.

You either specify all the implicits in the list, or you don't specify them at all. [According to the specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/07-implicits.html#implicit-parameters), if one parameter is marked as implicit, the entire argument list is marked as well:

> An implicit parameter list (`implicit p1, ……, pn`) of a method marks the parameters `p1, …, pn` as implicit.

---

> secondly, why does it's saying that that the parameter t is implicit?

Because of what was answered in your first part.

If you still want to invoke it like that, you can use `implicitly`:

```
test(implicitly, 10)
```

Generally, it is recommended that you require an implicit in a separate argument list:

```
def test[T](i: Int)(implicit ev: T <:< Int) = println(t)
```

Comment: +up for the spec reference.

Answer (score 3):

the problem is that the implicit parameter should be in its own list, like this:

```
def test[T](t : T)(implicit ev: T <:< Int) = println(t)
```

Give that a try!

Comment: Hm... so what does the declaration in my question mean? How does compiler interpret it?

Comment: It just means that both ev and t parameters are considered implicit. That's why the compiler states that t is implicit.

Comment: so we could just omit writing implicit multiple times if we want to declare more than one implicit parameter. Correct?

Comment: Yes that is correct and also using only one "implicit" at the start of a parameter list is the normal way to define an implicit parameter list.